# Vandalized top tube

Tags: frames, frugal

My bike was vandalized and the top tube is completely bust, is it possible to get this repaired/replaced?

[image]

any advice here would be great, thanks a lot.

Comment: Ouch! That's rough. I think unfortunately you are out of luck. The frame is aluminum and as such it does not lend itself well to being economically cut & welded, and certainly would not bend back into shape and retain any semblance of strength.

Comment: I would say even the remaining tubes would have undergone a lot of stress as the top tube was "shortened" pulling the head tube close to the seat tube. Depending on how good the components are, you might be better off finding a new/used frame rather than replacing the entire bike.

Comment: A lot of companies have a crash replacement policy.  They may sell you a replacement from at some percentage off of retail.  That's probably not as cost effective as finding a used frame and making the change yourself, but it's an option.

Comment: In Africa they'd bang it out straight, splice a piece of wood to the top tube (possibly with duct tape) and keep riding.  But by American/European standards it's a goner -- too apt to fail at other points, even if the top tube is somehow "made whole" again.

Comment: guessing- they were twisting the bike with the u-lock locked to the top tube?

Comment: What did you end up doing?  Can you please consider adding your own answer describing or showing what you did?  Closure is useful, it really helps later searchers who may have similar problems.

Answer (score 4):

First of all - that sucks - sorry that happened.
Your frame cannot be repaired.

You are in a real rough spot as the components are nice enough to reuse, but finding a frame in that style is going to be hard. Bicycle models that allow you to buy only the frame are high end models, and there aren't any high end city bikes. You don't want a mountain bike frame as they are designed for suspension length forks. Hopefully you can find a city (flat bar road) frame, but in absence of that, a road frame should work. If you can find a frame for less than $200 then give it a try. If you cannot swap out components yourself and have to pay a bike shop then it may be totaled.

Take it to a Giant dealer and ask them how much it costs to replace the frame. This price may be close to the cost of the bike.